# Indirect buffer in emacs org-mode to the right, not below

Tags: emacs, org-mode

Question about org-mode in emacs. After I create an agenda view with the `match` command, I'd like to work with the resulting agenda view as a table of contents, using it to trigger indirect buffers for the headlines in the agenda view, using `C-c C-x b`. Out of the box, that command creates an indirect buffer *below* the window with the agenda view. I'd like to create the buffer to the *right* of the agenda view, i.e., to have the new window placed as if I had created it with  `C-x 3` rather than `C-x 2`. I haven't been able to find either the prefix key or variable to customize.

Comment: `C-h v display-buffer-alist`.